# How to store the Local image path in sqlite or xml database in Xamrin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, xamarin.forms

I have given task to store the image path in database either xml schema or sqlite database.I am working on Xamarin.Forms PCL project.  I am very confused with how to store image path in database.because in android image should be placed in Ressource/drawble,ios image placed in Resources folder. I read [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) xamarin.forms documentaion. But not getting how to get path and store in database. Please anyone provide any resources or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hope you have gone through this documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/) and to distinguish between iOS and Android is also [Given here in this documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/platform-specifics/#Device.OS) .

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
    // Save in sqlite with iOS path
}if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android) {
    // Save in sqlite with Android path
}
```

Hope it helps.