# Get File Names in Resource directory

Tags: xamarin

I have a `Xamarin.Forms`  GetFiles.IOS project that has a "Resources" directory that's part of the project.  I have placed 25 files into the Resources Directory. I now want to be able to go to the resource directory and get all the file names.  I created some code to read the files in the directory but I'm getting a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
String dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var filePath = Path.Combine(dir,"Resources");
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);
```

I just can't seem to get the path correct!
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: It is rather a Xamarin.iOS question, you could just write code to list resources executing in the iOS native project, then access result data in Forms via dependency service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things necessary to have the files be copied into the app folder:

1. They need to be set with Build Action `Content` with Copy to Output Directory `Copy Always` in the `Properties` window.
2. They must be in a different custom folder than `Resources`.

Number 2. is because `Resources` is a special reserved directory name and even if you put some content files in it, it is never copied in the app bundle's folder. You can check for yourself, if you put the files in a folder `Test`, your code will work as intended.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . If that resolved your problem, please consider accepting the answer so that the question is displayed as resolved :-) .

Comment: I clicked the up arrow above the 0 to indicate the result was useful.. I don't know if this indicated the answer was resolved.

Comment: Oh, it is the grey "tick mark", it should be below the arrows :-) . You can upvote only after you get a few points on SO.

Comment: Only click it once so that it becomes green :-) .

Comment: The checkmark was there, but then it disappeared, I think you accidentally clicked it twice, please try it again. You get points for activity on the website like answering questions, but also for accepting answers (you get 2 points for each answer you accept) - here is more detailed info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: That is weird, still nothing :-D . The result should be that the green tick mark should stay there like for example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667108/how-to-store-the-local-image-path-in-sqlite-or-xml-database-in-xamrin-forms?rq=1

Comment: Awsome, now it worked :-) ! You now have three reputation points :-) .

Comment: the check was gray! i tapped it again and ir turned green! hope this works !